# How to set Plotly to replace the default lists to iplot with specific colors and widths?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plotly

I can specify lists of colors and widths to plot in matplotlib, for illustration:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib._color_data as mcd

cXJO = mcd.XKCD_COLORS["xkcd:black"]
cXDJ = mcd.XKCD_COLORS["xkcd:fuchsia"]
cXEJ = mcd.XKCD_COLORS["xkcd:green"]

lineColor = (cXJO, cXDJ, cXEJ)
lineType = (3, 2, 1)

for i in range(plotList):
    ax.plot(index, df[i], color=lineColor[i], linewidth=lineType[i])
```

I need to present the same colors and lines by iPlot in Plotly for interative media sharing. Possible to do the same as simply as matplotlib per attached chart?

[image: ASX-IndexASX-20170519]

Answer (score 0):

Good examples in Plotly that may be relevant for reference:

https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/